# Used sesame oil instead of soy sauce - can I rescue marinade?

Tags: chicken, breadcrumbs

I am making panko chicken, for which I marinate the chicken in low sodium soy sauce and lemon. I ran out of the soy sauce and needed an additional 2 tbsp of it. I remembered I had bought a small bottle of it but it was a different brand. I accidentally poured sesame oil. Now I don't know what to do. Can I make something else from the mixture, and what other ingredients should I then put in?

Comment: Is this just in the marinade? Doesn't the oil float? You could probably just spoon most of it off the top... I don't know that it will really hurt anything. Anyway, the recipe for your "panko chicken" would be helpful.

Comment: You should also use better titles when writing a question. I have edited it (pending review)

Comment: Was this regular sesame oil, or toasted sesame oil?  (toasted is much more strongly flavored)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to rescue the marinade, sesame oil isn't going to ruin it, just add more soy sauce to get the saltiness you need. Sesame oil isn't going to impart much flavor to the meat in the marinade However, if you plan to use the marinade as a sauce then keep in mind that

- Sesame oil is not going to add much flavor to the meat while it is marinaded, however is will add a lot of flavor to the cooked result, perhaps too much
- That much oil could make your end result a bit greasy in texture
- Sesame oil has a low smoke point and will burn and produce off flavors if added to the bottom of a hot pan, I recommend adding it to liquid

I would suggest if you plan to use the marinade as a sauce just add a little bit of it and add soy separately to the dish to make up for it.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with sesame oil. You will get a slightly different flavor. As it's an oil, you may want to reduce the amount of oil elsewhere.

Having slightly less soy sauce than described in you recipe doesn't really affect anything (apart from additional soy flavor).

Comment: Harmless if it is untoasted sesame oil (which nobody would mistake for soy sauce drunk!). Toasted is a very potent aromatic.

Answer (score 0):

2tbsp of sesame oil is a lot, if it is toasted sesame oil (the variant most easily mistaken for soy sauce). Certainly too overwhelming for a japanese style dish, you crossed the border to korea(n food) here. Consider finding a recipe for a korean (eg bulgogi) marinade, and add the rest of the needed ingredients too...